# Crash due to requiring READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission even though it's in the Manifest

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I've got the task of updating an Android application that was previously built with the following settings:

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

I downloaded the latest Android Studio and ended up changing these to the following to get the app to build:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

The previously built app worked perfectly without any crash. Unfortunately when I build it now the app crashes with the following exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=2476, uid=10053 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()`

Even though the permission is clearly in the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   package="com.dbotha.app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The crash occurs at the point of loading a cursor for `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`:

```
new CursorLoader(
                this,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{
                        MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID
                },
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
```

I'm a little bit stumped as to what to do beyond ripping the whole component out and reimplementing from scratch -- which I'd prefer to avoid ;)

Comment: Hi,
Do you use camera in this app?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> exists in the Manifest but at least right now I don't believe the app has any Camera functionality. The crash is occurring as the result of trying to look for Images on the SD Card to show in a custom photo gallery view.

Comment: Have you clean/rebuild the application after adding the permission to the manifest?

Comment: I would recommend a full uninstall/reinstall of the app.

Comment: @SubOptimal I've cleaned are rebuilt many times ;)

Comment: @CommonsWare I've done a full uninstall/reinstall on my HTC One but the issue still persists, the same on my emulators.

Comment: @dbotha Only to be sure that no stale artefacts are reused, which do not contain the permissions. So from the list of possible reasons we can remove this case. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that a project dependency had a `maxSDKVersion` attribute in the libraries in `AndroidManifest.xml` for these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

During the manifest merge process that attribute would get included and break things on any device running above API version 18.

One approach to fixing this is to add the following applications manifest that will ensure the `maxSdkVersion` attributes don't make it into the merged `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...>

<uses-permission tools:node="replace" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission tools:node="replace" android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```